# Drawing a 'line of arrows' with the same distance between them

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, nodes, paths

I have a rectangle node and want to draw multiple arrows showing in one direction and have a fixed distance between each other.

The drawback of my current MWE is that the distances written in the foreach-statement are manually try and error as an equal distance between two values will not result in equal distance between the arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw](down){this is a very long test node};
\node[rectangle, draw, above of = down](up){this is a very long test node};
\foreach \x in {165,150, 90, 30, 15}
{\draw (down.\x) to ++ (0,.4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The picture looks as follows [**this is wanted**]:

[image]

Using a more automatic generated way like saying this pattern:

```
\foreach \x in {160, 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100, 90}
{\draw (down.\x) to ++ (0,.4);}
```

This result in this one [**not wanted**]:

[image]

Is therre a better way to create arrow going from one nodeside in one direction or to use the postitionmarks of a node (160, 155, ...) 'better' without just try and error?

Comment: According to page 136, when you write (down.10) 10 is the measurement of an angle. Measured from the center of the node.

Comment: so there is no implemented way to call specific points at the node shape? let's say we 'unwrap' the node-edges and segment the line intervall-like marks from 0-100?

Comment: It's something to write yourself as @marmot just did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One out of many possibilities. More fancy possibilities arise with the calc library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw](down){this is a very long test node};
\node[rectangle, draw, above of = down](up){this is a very long test node};
\foreach \x [count=\y] in {0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9}
{\path (down.north west) -- (down.north east) coordinate[pos=\x] (p\y);
\draw (p\y) to (up.south -| p\y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow, i was never thinking of such an approach, great. i have never used calc before, will this will make the process much nicer or easier? However I think I will start using you idea

Answer (score 2):

Like `marmot's` solution but with `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw](down){this is a very long test node};
\node[rectangle, draw, above of = down](up){this is a very long test node};
\foreach \x in {0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9}
\draw ($(up.south west)!\x!(up.south east)$) coordinate (aux) -- (aux|-down.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]